# ServiceStack getting cookies

Tags: servicestack

How can I access the request cookies in a service?

Note: I'm using the old version of servicestack: 3.9.33.0 (got a lot of this warnings: 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService' is obsolete: 'Use IService - ServiceStack's New API for future services'    )

My services are defined like this:

```
public class TableService : IService<TableRequest>, IService<NextStepRequest>, IService<SaveNextStepRequest>, IService<SaveCellTextRequest>, IService<SaveCommentsRequest>, IService<UpdateTimestampRequest>, IService<DateTimeTestRequest>, IService<CreateNewIssueRequest>, IService<IssueTypesRequest>, IService<LookupItemsRequest>, IService<UpdateColumnOrderRequest>, IService<CancelSiteDialogDataRequest>, IService<CancelSiteRequest>, IService<QuerySiteNamesRequest>, IService<MapQueryRequest>, IService<TtsignInfoRequest>, IService<CheckListItemRequest>, IService<SiteStatusRequest>
{ 
    public TableService(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object Execute(TableRequest request)
    {
         // How can I access the cookies here?
    }
    .....
```

Since I'm using an old version of the framework I'm a bit unsure if the current documentation applies to it. If so please just point me in the right direction.

(Yes, I know I should upgrade, but a lot of code running, and just need to do a minor fix. And since I'm not covered with a complete set of unittest I'm afraid of doing a upgrade )

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer. Just implement `IRequiresRequestContext` and the request context will be injected. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services

Comment: It's been a while since I was working with servicestack, but this got me remembering what a nice framework this is